# OpenCV to close the window on a specific key?

Tags: python, image, opencv, window

It seems really simple, but I can't get it to work and the couldn't find any questions regarding this particular issue (if there are, please point out in the comments).

I am showing an image and want the window to close on a specific key, but strangely, **any key causes it to close**.

This is my simple code for testing:

```
img = cv2.imread("MyImage.png")
cv2.imshow('My Image', img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
print(k)
if k == 27:  # close on ESC key
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

(based on what is said [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html))

No matter what key I press, the key code is shown (27 for ESC, 32 for SPACE, ...) and the window closes.

**The main problem:** the `if` clause is never reached (I checked by putting the `print(k)` inside it, and nothing is printed). After the key press, the program simply stops running and it doesn't get to checking the key code.

(I am on macOS Catalina, with Python 3.8)

So, how do I actually make it wait for a specific key?

Comment: If the shown code is everything, your program ends, and thus all windows are closed anyway. Put some loop around the key reading, for example.

Comment: I just tried it on my computer and it worked perfectly: /

Comment: @HansHirse, you were exactly right! I added an infinite while loop with `waitKey(0)` and it worked perfectly! Although, I am surprised why the above code seems to work for some? (also maybe post your comment as an answer so I accept it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my point of view, your program just terminates, and thus all windows are implicitly closed, regardless of which key you press.

One idea might be to put a `while True` loop around the reading and checking of the pressed key:

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png')
cv2.imshow('My Image', img)
while True:
    k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
    print(k)
    if k == 27:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Running this, pressing some keys, and finally <kbd>ESC</kbd>, I get the following output:

```
103
100
102
27
```

Also, all windows are closed, and the program is terminated.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:     Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:       3.8.5
OpenCV:       4.4.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: I did basically the same thing with a simpler `while cv2.waitKey(0) != 27: pass`, but your idea was spot on. Thanks.

Comment: I see the numbers when I press a key, but the image window does not close.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use specific key, you can use `ord()`:

```
img = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png')
cv2.imshow('My Image', img)

while True:
    k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
    print(k)
    if k == ord('c'): # you can put any key here
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will wait for key 'q' to be pressed.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("MyImage.png")
cv2.imshow('My Image', img)
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

HIH.

Comment: Didn't help. Still closing on any key press. Interestingly, when I put a `print('sth')` inside the above `if`, it doesn't run and exists without printing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
img = cv2.imread("MyImage.png")
cv2.imshow('My Image', img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
print(k)
if k == 27:  # close on ESC key
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have simply removed `& 0xFF` from it. This works for me but I don't why this would pose a problem as it is simply applying and operation with `FF`.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference on my machine. Same behavior with or without `0xFF`